# How to append some line matched to previous line matched with sed?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, video-subtitles

For example, transfer below

```
00:00:10.730
this presentation is delivered by the

00:00:13.230
Stanford center for professional

00:00:14.610
development okay so let's get started

00:00:25.500
with today's material so um welcome back

00:00:32.399
to the second lecture what I want to do
```

to

```
00:00:10.730 --> 00:00:13.230
this presentation is delivered by the

00:00:13.230 --> 00:00:14.610
Stanford center for professional

00:00:14.610 --> 00:00:25.500
development okay so let's get started

00:00:25.500 --> 00:00:32.399
with today's material so um welcome back

00:00:32.399
to the second lecture what I want to do
```

Comment: Use something like [gaupol](http://otsaloma.io/gaupol/) for munging subtitles?

Answer (score 2):

For sake of code clarity, we are using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -nE '

   /^([0-9][0-9]:){2}[0-9]+[.][0-9]+/!{p;d;}

   h;:a
      $bb;n;H
   /^([0-9][0-9]:){2}[0-9]+[.][0-9]+/!ba

   :b
   x
   y/\n_/_\n/
   s/^([^_]*)_(.*)_([^_]*)$/\1 ---> \3_\2/
   y/\n_/_\n/

   p;g;$!s/^/\n/;D

' yourfile
```

---

### Results

```
00:00:10.730 ---> 00:00:13.230
this presentation is delivered by the

00:00:13.230 ---> 00:00:14.610
Stanford center for professional

00:00:14.610 ---> 00:00:25.500
development okay so let's get started

00:00:25.500 ---> 00:00:32.399
with today's material so um welcome back

00:00:32.399
to the second lecture what I want to do
```

---

### Explanation

- We keep range of lines from number to next number.
- Then at the end of range, the last portion is brought forward and the range printed, also the pattern space is cleared out and the end of range used to fill it and then using this value of pattern space, the control is transferred to the top of sed code for starting the cycle all over again from the current end of range till the next number or till we hit the eof.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed` and `tac`:

```
tac file | \
sed -E '/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}$/ { H; x; s/^\n//; s/\n/ --> /; }' | \
tac
```

The same could be written with traditional `sed` (i.e. without `-E`), but it would be more verbose.

With GNU `awk` and `tac`:

```
tac file | \
gawk --re-interval '
    /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3} --> / { old = $1 }
    /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}$/ { if(old != "") $0 = $0 " --> " old; old = $1 }
    1' | \
tac
```

Please note that the `awk` version can handle time intervals such as `00:00:14.610 --> 00:00:25.500` in the input file, while the `sed` version is fooled by them.

Note also that `tac` can be emulated with `sed`:

```
sed -n '1!G; $p; h'
```

or like this:

```
sed '1!G; h; $!d'
```

However both forms will load the entire input file in memory, so they aren't very efficient.

Result:

```
00:00:10.730 --> 00:00:13.230
this presentation is delivered by the

00:00:13.230 --> 00:00:14.610
Stanford center for professional

00:00:14.610 --> 00:00:25.500
development okay so let's get started

00:00:25.500 --> 00:00:32.399
with today's material so um welcome back

00:00:32.399
to the second lecture what I want to do
```

Answer (score 1):

With single ***gawk*** approach for relatively "small" (by size) files:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS=""; FS="[[:space:]]+" }
     {   c++; 
         a[c]["t"]=$1; 
         a[c]["s"]=substr($0,length($1)+2) 
     }
     END { 
         len=length(a); 
         for(i=1;i<=len;i++) { 
             if((i+1)<=len){ printf("%s --> %s\n%s\n\n",a[i]["t"],a[i+1]["t"],a[i]["s"]) } 
             else { printf("%s\n%s\n",a[i]["t"],a[i]["s"]) }
         } 
     }' file
```

The output:

```
00:00:10.730 --> 00:00:13.230
this presentation is delivered by the

00:00:13.230 --> 00:00:14.610
Stanford center for professional

00:00:14.610 --> 00:00:25.500
development okay so let's get started

00:00:25.500 --> 00:00:32.399
with today's material so um welcome back

00:00:32.399
to the second lecture what I want to do
```

Comment: This loads the entire file in memory.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, added a note to my answer. Might be used for "small" files

Answer (score 0):

I see loops or piping to other tools in the given answers, and I don't like that if it is not neccessary. I like one-liners:

```
sed -E '/^[0-9:.]+$/{x;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)\n(\n)(.*)/\1 --> \4\3\2\3/p;d;};H;$!d;x'
```

But let's go step by step:

- I use `^[0-9:.]+$` as extended regular expression for the time stamp line. This should be sufficient in the real world, but feel free to make it more precise. I use this pattern as an address, so everything inside the `{}` pair is executed for the timestamp lines only.
- Obviously we need to keep everything in mind until the next timestamp comes. Keeping in mind means appending to the hold space in `sed`
- Thus, each time we meet a timestamp, we assume everything since the last time stamp resides in the hold space. So we append the current timestamp to the `H`old space and e`x`change pattern and hold space. This way the current time stamp is already save in the hold space for the next cycle, while everything we need, is in the pattern space
- We just need to reorganize it with `s`ubstitute: `s/(.*)\n(.*)\n(\n)(.*)/\1 --> \4\3\2\3/` -- `\1` is the starting timestamp, `\2` is the text line, `\3` is a newline (we need that in the replacement, but POSIX doesn't define `\n` in the replacement) and `\4` is the ending time stamp. Looks more complicated than it is.
- Adding option `p` to the `s`ubstitution and then `d`eleting the pattern space keeps us from unwanted output for the first line when the hold space was still empty.
- Now all what's left is to append other lines to the `H`old space and
- for the last line e`x`change buffers again, so lines collected in the hold space will get printed even without closing timestamp

If someone still feels `sed` is not elegant, I can't help.